2-year working Ubuntu install suddenly fails, reinstalls all fail too
Until two days ago, I had been running an Ubuntu 22.04 install just fine since it was released. Two days ago I started getting some weird errors which stopped my machine learning development stuff from working. I don't remember exactly what these errors were off the top of my head (sorry, if I knew my PC would fail to reboot I would have saved them), but I think they were NVidia-related. Anyway, at this point I attempt to reboot and get nothing. See links below for some videos showing exactly what "nothing" means.
At this point, I move on to running Boot-Repair from the bootable USB I have for just such cases, which has always fixed such problems in the past. No dice. OK, annoying, but not a huge deal. I have backups and scripts for getting my environments and everything set up rapidly, so I'll just reinstall Ubuntu, a couple hours and I'll be back up and running. Nope, this doesn't work either.
I am on day three of this problem now. I have tried installing Ubuntu 22.04, 23.10, and the 24.04 beta. I have tried all three of these on two disks - the original SSD I previously had the working 22.04 install on, and a brand new NVMe M.2 drive I bought specifically for this purpose. Everything I try results in the exact same problem I got upon reboot after the previously-working install suddenly failed. To be exact, that problem is this:
https://youtu.be/o336q3GMMvY https://youtu.be/CSJC5piuKM4 (LOL sorry these are upside-down, dunno what happened there...)
Either one of these two things happens. Sometimes, as in the first vid, I get to a screen with a non-flashing cursor where I cannot type anything (no inputs produce any effect, have tried every key on my keyboard), or I just land on a black screen. Last night I left the unblinking cursor screen up overnight just to see if it was actually doing anything in the background. Also nope - I woke up to the same screen.
This install of Ubuntu worked fine for years, then just failed one day after no hardware changes or software updates that I'm aware of, and now any new install fails to work as if my PC has an immune system that just spontaneously developed an Ubuntu allergy. It doesn't work on either old hardware or new hardware.
I was previously dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10, each located on separate drives. I am now attempting to single boot Ubuntu. All attempts to install Ubuntu have been done by downloading the ISO on Windows 10, writing it to a live USB with Rufus, shutting the PC down, removing the Windows 10 SSD, then letting the installer do its thing (using the recommended install or whatever it's called, i.e. I have changed no partition/installer settings at all) on either the SSD I previously used for Ubuntu, or the new NVMe M.2 drive that I just bought.
Hardware specs:
  MPG B550 GAMING PLUS Motherboard
  AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core 3.70 GHz
  16GB RAM
  GPU: Nvidia RTX 3080

Did you try to check memory?

Did the Win install work?

Hahah, thanks for the quick replies on this, guys. I actually forgot I asked this question. The answer to both of your questions is yes. I did solve this problem though.
I was specifically avoiding the 'install proprietary gpu drivers' during Ubuntu install because I do ML dev so I need specialized gpu drivers and didn't want to have to strip out irrelevant ones once the OS install finished. Turns out that's what was causing the startup failures.
NO idea what caused the initial OS failure though. Likely gpu driver related since it produced same symptoms. ¯\(ツ)/¯
